# Prisma nextauth not working when i change the user model name from User to XYZUser

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth, supabase

situation - building using nextjs - next-auth - prisma adapter and supabase for user auth. the application auth works fine when my db prisma model was called User. however since changing the model name from User to WebUser it no longer works and i get an error from next-auth 'GetUserByEmailError'. as soon as i update the migration and change it back to User i can then register/login. has anyone had this issue/ know if its possible to use different db model names for users when integrating next-auth?

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share your working schema with the "User" config? I have the same database config and I am getting the "GetUserByEmailError" msg even if my model name is "User".

Comment: https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/prisma - there is a base schema there to use

Comment: doesnt work for my linkedin OR email provider

Comment: The docs provide a good coverage, I’m trying to find an answer to the above

Answer (score 0):

When using the Prisma adapater, you the table to be called `User` on the public schema: https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/prisma#create-the-prisma-schema-from-scratch

When using Supabase, you can alternatively use the Supabase Adapter which will use a separate schema called `next_auth`: https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/supabase

And also makes it easier to work with RLS: https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/supabase#enabling-row-level-security-rls